# Swift static tableview with dynamic section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableviewcontroller, with 2 sections.

First(static) section have 2 rows, and second section should be dynamic.

Storyboard:
[image]

Code:

```
class DocumentInventoryChangeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var results: [String] = ["Dog", "Cat", "Snake", "Test"]    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DocumentInventoryCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DocumentInventoryCell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 1 {
            return results.count
        }
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        } else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DocumentInventoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = results[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

But i'm getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>
> '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty
>   NSArray'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it was enough to override these methods in `UITableViewController`:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
tableView(tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int
```

If you want to have custom table view cell in your table view, you need to crate subclass of `UITableViewCell` also with nib, and register it to your table view.

My whole controller looks like this:

```
var data = ["Ahoj", "Hola", "Hello"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 1 {
        return data.count
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        print(data[indexPath.row])
    }
}

@IBAction func addItem() {
    data.append("Item \(data.count)")
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: data.count - 1, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: .Left)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

@IBAction func removeItem() {
    if data.count > 0 {
        data.removeLast()
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: data.count, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: .Left)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: adding indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath fixed the issue for me. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no such thing as a table view where the "First(static) section have 2 rows, and second section should be dynamic." Your table view needs to be entirely dynamic; that is, it should show a prototype cell, not static contents, in the storyboard, and its entire contents should be configured in code, including the first section — even though the first section never changes.

Comment: This is far from true, I've personally overridden static table views numerous times and implemented dynamic behaviors in different sections depending on data. This is something that is completely possible. The main thing is you need to call super.tableView.whatevermethodyou'reoverridding, when appropriate.

Comment: @TheCodingArt The fact that the Cocoa framework can be subverted doesn't make it right to do.

Comment: Subverted? A static tableview only pre configures certain things for you. There's nothing special about it other than a preconfigured datasource. Subclassing is a natural extension of public behavior aka programming 101.